# getting error while creating dynamic action and passing variable to request mapping in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have written one controller class, in which i am writing one request mapping method which in turn will call another method with request mapping (but this time with some path variable)

Exception encountered:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{50}"

```
Controller class :

@Controller
public class CompanyController {

....other code.........


    @RequestMapping("/companySave.do")
    public String saveCompany(Map<String, Object> map, @ModelAttribute("company")
    Company company, BindingResult result)
    {   

        map.put("success", "success");

        companyService.saveCompany(company);


        return "redirect:/companyAddressSave/{"+company.getId()+"}.do";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/companyAddressSave/{id}.do")
    public String saveAddressCompany(@PathVariable("id") String id,Map<String, Object> map, @ModelAttribute("company")
    Company company, BindingResult result)
    {   map.put("Success", "Success");
        map.put("company", companyService.getCompany(Long.parseLong(id)));
        System.out.println("Hi");       
        return "add-compnay-master";
    }




}
```

can anybody tell me if i am doing any mistake while passing path variable..???
thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass along the curly braces:

```
return "redirect:/companyAddressSave/"+company.getId()+".do";
```